# Page (Session) is too hard cached

Tags: caching, iis-7, session-state, outputcache

I´m working on a webforms app and I get to the point where I can´t get the unique Session.SessionId for the user, instead the clients recieve the same ID, probably because this is too hard cached somewhere. In my local environment, I don´t have this problem but on the test/live servers there is.

Can this have something to do with the IIS and some setting there perhaps?

Thanks.